# jQuery add and remove $(window).scroll(function()?

Tags: jquery, window, scrolltop

How can I remove and then add the `$(window).scroll`? I need to store a variable and reuse it after some event.

```
// here i store my var
$(window).scroll(function(){
    myScroll = $(window).scrollTop()  
});

$("#itemUnbind").click(function(){
    // here i need to remove the listener        
});

$("#itemBind").click(function(){
    // here i need to add listener again     
});
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You need to store the function in a variable and then use [`off`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) to remove it:

```
var scrollHandler = function(){
    myScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
}

$("#itemBind").click(function(){
    $(window).scroll(scrollHandler);
}).click(); // .click() will execute this handler immediately

$("#itemUnbind").click(function(){
    $(window).off("scroll", scrollHandler);
});
```

Comment: @Dee - if this works for you, please mark it as the answer by clicking on the "tick" icon.

Comment: I think this should be:
$("#itemUnbind").click(function(){
    $(window).unbind("scroll", scrollHandler);
});

Comment: @JackAllan: you'd think somebody else might have noticed that in the past 2 years! While the old solution would have worked for most people, it would have unbound all handlers for the event.

Comment: you should consider editing your answer to reflect that.

Comment: @gdbj: I did, almost 3 years ago.  The difference is I used `off` instead of `unbind` (the latter is deprecated).

Comment: for me the `.off` is not work - I try the `unbind` and works