# JQuery Mobile User scroll to bottom

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

With the following code, I am trying to find when the user scrolls to the bottom of the page. In JQuery mobile.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
     if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
          alert("The Bottom");
     }
});
```

For now I am just wanting it to output that they have reached the bottom.

My problem is, when the site loads, it will output this message. When I scroll to the bottom it will then output the alert.

Is there a way to stop it doing it for when the page has loaded and only do it when the user has physically scrolled the page?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is it because your content is shorter than your page?  Meaning that when it loads, you are already at the bottom.  I have tried to replicate your problem here http://jsfiddle.net/qESXR/2/  and it behaves like you want.  However if I shorten the content and run it locally on my machine I get the same result you have.
If so, you might check for the height of the page vs height of your html using these

```
$(window).height();   // returns height of browser viewport

$(document).height(); // returns height of HTML document
```

like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(document).height() > $(window).height())
    {
        if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
          alert("The Bottom");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah, the data is loaded in dynamically. so the initial load it is empty, but once the data is inserted into the DOM it obviously expands.

Comment: Sounds like you need to add the scroll dynamically after you load the content.  If so here is a good resource http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306387/jquery-add-and-remove-window-scrollfunction

Comment: Thank you so much! this has been driving me insane!!

Comment: @Rory: could you perhaps post the solution you ended up with? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that jQuery Mobile's [page widget](http://api.jquerymobile.com/page/) treats each "page" as the window as far as scrolling goes. To detect when the user has scrolled to the end, bind the scroll function to `$(document)` instead:

http://jsfiddle.net/5x6T2/

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
        alert("Bottom reached!");
    }
});
```